# Using the value of observeAsState() in an if statement, causes major UI lag

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a login page with two TextFields, one for the username and one for the password. When the submit button is clicked, I call my loginViewModel's `login(username,passwd)` method in order to asynchronously authenticate the user. Once the authentication result is received, I post the value to the ViewModel's mutableLiveData in order for the value to be observed in my Login composable through `loginViewModel.wasLoginSuccessful.observeAsState(false)`.
The problem occurs with the `if (isUserAuthenticated) onSuccessfulLogin()` since when the authentication result is `true`, I successfully get "redirected" to the home page but everything is super laggy, and using the profiler I can see the Memory & CPU usage fluctuating a lot. If I remove the if statement and make it so that the `onSuccessfullLogin()` is called unconditionally, everything works just fine without any issues. I'm guessing that this is a side-effect through recomposition and/or a memory leak but I can't pinpoint it.

Login page:

```
@Composable
fun Login(navController: NavController) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        LoginContent() {
            navController.navigate(Screens.DASHBOARD_MYEWAY.navRoute) {
                popUpTo(0)
            }
        }
        LoginFooter() {
            navController.navigate(NavigationGraphs.ACTIVATION.route)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun LoginContent(onSuccessfulLogin: () -> Unit) {
    val loginViewModel: LoginViewModel = remember { getKoin().get() }
    val isUserAuthenticated by loginViewModel.wasLoginSuccessful.observeAsState(false)
    val username = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val password = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        TopBarPadding()
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(24.fixedDp()))
        Text(
            text = LocalContext.current.getString(R.string.welcome_plural),
            fontSize = 32.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            color = colorResource(id = R.color.Black_100),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.fixedDp()))
        Text(
            text = LocalContext.current.getString(R.string.please_enter_password_to_proceed),
            fontSize = 18.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            color = colorResource(id = R.color.Black_100)
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(30.fixedDp()))
        InputField(
            label = LocalContext.current.getString(R.string.username),
            onTextChangeCallback = { username.value = it })
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(26.fixedDp()))
        InputField(
            label = LocalContext.current.getString(R.string.password),
            isPassword = true,
            canReveal = true,
            onTextChangeCallback = { password.value = it })
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(32.fixedDp()))
        MyButton(text = LocalContext.current.getString(R.string.login),
            buttonType = MyButtonType.PRIMARY,
            onClick = {
                scope.launch {
                    loginViewModel.login(username.value, password.value)
                }
            })
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(24.fixedDp()))
        Link(text = LocalContext.current.getString(R.string.forgot_my_password))
    }
    if (isUserAuthenticated) onSuccessfulLogin()
}

@Composable
private fun LoginFooter(onClickEwayActivation: () -> Unit) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
            Text(
                text = LocalContext.current.getString(R.string.you_have_no_username),
                fontSize = 14.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                color = colorResource(id = R.color.Black_100)
            )
            Row {
                Text(
                    text = LocalContext.current.getString(R.string.do_string),
                    fontSize = 14.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    color = colorResource(id = R.color.Black_100)
                )
                Link(
                    text = LocalContext.current.getString(R.string.my_eway_activation),
                    onClick = { onClickEwayActivation() })
            }
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(40.fixedDp()))
    }
}
```

LoginViewModel:

```
class LoginViewModel(
    private val authenticationUseCase: AuthenticationControllerUseCase
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _loginResult = MutableLiveData(false)
    val wasLoginSuccessful: LiveData<Boolean> = _loginResult

    fun login(username: String, password: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            when (val response = authenticationUseCase.validateUser(username, password)) {
                is ResponseResult.Success -> {
                    response.data?.userLoginId!!.saveStringThroughKeystore(PreferenceKeys.ACCOUNT_ID.key)
                    _loginResult.postValue(true)
                }
                is ResponseResult.Error -> {
                    _loginResult.postValue(false)
                    Log.d(
                        "USER_VALIDATION_ERROR",
                        "Network Call Failed With Exception: " + response.exception.message
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling callback functions such as `onSuccessfulLogin` during compositon is a bad idea. Can you try replacing that with `LaunchedEffect(isUserAuthenticated){ if(isUserAuthenticated) onSuccessfulLogin()}`?

Comment: @AdrianK This seems to have fixed the issue! Was the error caused because after the button was clicked, the state would change thus recomposition would be triggered while navigating to another screen? Shouldn't the recomposition only affect us if we were to remain in the same screen where that initial composable (the Login one in this case) is? I decided to use a callback instead of passing a navController since that's not a good practice but I wouldn't have thought that it would need to run inside a coroutine. Why is that?

Comment: the default `NavHost` transitions between screens with a bit of cross-fade. To achieve that, both source and target destinations are rendered at the same time with different opacity. During that transition, multiple recompositions might happen, causing your `LoginContent` to execute the callback each time. As a rule of thumb, callbacks should only be called during listeners like `clickable` or if they depend on a state change in a `LaunchedEffect`

Comment: @AdrianK Thank you for the excellent explanation. Mind submitting everything as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Hey @AdrianK just pinging you to remind you to post an answer if possible so that I can accept it :)